# GVim extra linespace

Tags: vim, gvim

I recently installed GVim and set the font to DejaVu Sans Mono size 11, but I noticed that there are 2 pixel lines between the lines, making the lines look apart. With linespace set to -2, the spacing looks correct (I compared it with gedit), but it has problem with some characters, for example, the underscore '_' cannot be displayed. Is this a bug in GVim? I am using Ubuntu 15.04.

Here is a screenshot comparing GVim and gedit side by side, https://i.stack.imgur.com/occi1.png

EDIT: add a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

How did you install GVim? From terminal with

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

or from software centre? I have installed GVim from software center and set my font as you said. Everything is fine!